# QMessageBox Output

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qmessagebox

Have a good day to all,
I'm trying to create a exit button in `menuBar()`. My point is, when user click the close button, `QMessageBox()` will be pop up to ask `QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No`. According to signal, I want to close the program.

To test the code, I just use `print()`. However results is &No or &Yes, rather than only No or Yes. What is the reason of that ? I couldn't figure out.

Here is my code,

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        self.ui()
        self.menu()

        self.show()

    def ui(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Basic")
        self.setGeometry(100, 50, 1080, 640)

    def menu(self):
        mainmenu = self.menuBar()
        filemenu = mainmenu.addMenu("File")

        file_close = QAction("Close", self)
        file_close.setShortcut("Ctrl+Q")
        file_close.triggered.connect(self.close_func1)

        filemenu.addAction(file_close)

    def close_func1(self):  # Ask Yes | No Question
        msg = QMessageBox()
        msg.setWindowTitle("Warning!")
        msg.setText("Would you like to exit ?")
        msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Question)
        msg.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No)
        msg.setDefaultButton(QMessageBox.No)
        msg.buttonClicked.connect(self.close_func2)
        x = msg.exec()

    def close_func2(self, i):  # In this section code decide to close it or not with if statement
        print(i.text())


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = Window()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: If there is a better way to do my target, I will be glad to hear that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to decide the outcome of the program based on the result of the button clicked, the simplest solution is to check the result of the [`exec()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#exec) method, which returns a [`StandardButton`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#StandardButton-enum) enumeration (and *not* a [`DialogCode`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#DialogCode-enum) as a QDialog normally does).

```
    def close_func1(self):  # Ask Yes | No Question
        # ...
        x = msg.exec()
        if x == msg.Yes:
            QApplication.quit()
```